# get build status during build step in team city

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a build in team city which runs a suite of tests. If the build is successful, I want to send an update to a third party service to let that service know the result, either passed or failed.

I will be feeding that information into a powershell script.

I want this to be done as the final build step, so I want to be able to access the current build status as a variable during a build step. I have seen it's possible to get useful variables like %build.number% but I can't see how I can get the build status

Comment: I don't see a pre-existing build property for success.  Can you make your own and set it to True at the beginning, and just change it to failed if any tests fail?

Comment: it's a good suggestion, but I can't see a way at the moment to trigger something when the tests fail. A slight variation which I can see is if I set a home made build property to false, then have another step which only runs if all previous step were successful, which updates it to true